# importmap with anggularjs some time cause error `A controller with this name is not registered`

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps

**Importmap config:**

```
pin "application", preload: true
pin "home", preload: true
```

**application layout:**

```
<body id="page-top" ng-app="userApp" ng-strict-di>
  <nav class="header shadow" ng-controller="NavbarController as vm" ng-init="vm.init()">
  </nav>

  <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
  <%= yield :javascript %>
</body>
```

**Home page**

```
<% content_for :javascript do %>
  <%= javascript_import_module_tag "home" %>
<% end %>
```

**application.js**

```
// AngularJs
import {} from 'libs/angular/angular.min'
import {} from 'libs/angular/angular-animate.min'
import {} from 'libs/angular/angular-cookies.min'
import {} from 'libs/angular/angular-sanitize.min'
import {} from 'libs/angular/angular-messages.min'
import {} from 'libs/angular/toaster.min'
import {} from 'angular/common'
import {} from 'angular/app'
```

**home.js**

```
import {} from 'angular/controllers/navbar_controller'
```

when I reload page (command+shift+R) sometime I get an error like

```
Error: $controller:ctrlreg
A controller with this name is not registered.
The controller with the name 'NavbarController' is not registered.
```

https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/docs/error/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=NavbarController

If I put all `home.js` to `application.js` it will be ok. But, I just want to separate many small files and only load what the page uses. What wrong with this code?